# How to create unique Hash for each row having null value in column in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hash, apache-spark-sql

We have below dataframe in Spark Scala:

| firstname | middlename | lastname | dob | gender | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | Rose | null | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 |
| Michael | null | Rose | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 |
| null | Michael | Rose | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 |

Here, we want to create unique `row_hash` for each row's data in other dataframe.
So, applying below transformation:

`val df2 = df.withColumn("row_hash", hash(df.columns.map(col):_*))`

And getting below:

| firstname | middlename | lastname | dob | gender | salary | row_hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | Rose | null | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 | -613328421 |
| Michael | null | Rose | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 | -613328421 |
| null | Michael | Rose | 2000-05-19 | M | 4000 | -613328421 |

I want to treat each of these rows as different and want to get unique `row_hash` for these. How can I achieve that?

Comment: do you want to treat these special cases as unique records or across the dataframe ?

Comment: Perhaps, replace using straight column values in your hash calculation with `ifnull(col,'colname')`.

Comment: @Vaebhav: Yes. I want to treat these all three rows of data unique and want to get unique row_hash for each one. Don't want to use any extra column field(like providing serial number against each row etc). Want to make hash from original data only.

Comment: @mazaneicha: Could please elaborate more. I couldn't get exactly what did you mean. Better, please write full line of code snippet implementing your logic/idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Add a unique id firstly. E.g.
>
> ```
> val dfy = dfx.withColumn("seqVal", functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
> ```
>
> Then apply the hash (and drop that extra column).

Or

> Alternatively, replace the null value with a value unlikely to occur
> in any of the columns under consideration, dynamically or statically, then apply the hash. That said, the 1st option is a blanket consideration.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.
Without adding any extra column, is there no way? Is there any other Hashing function in Spark Scala which take care of these type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Build a string with column values separated by some special character(s) which doesn't occur within your regular values. E.g. `Michael::Rose:2000-05-19:M:4000`. Or just replace nulls with some special values as offered by others. Then calculate hash from these values.